# How much faster if write in-line assembly rather than regular c/c++ code?

Tags: c++, c, assembly

One of my senior collegues optimizes a function (he is implementing image filtering) by writing in-line assembly. Is that really necessary? Wouldn't modern compiler do that for us? Typically, how much gain do we have by converting C code into assembly?  If assembly code really brings lots of benefits, when should we convert C/C++ code into assembly and when should we leave the code as it is, since assembly code is hard to read and maintain.

Comment: Measure it see if there is an improvement. If the improvement is not greater than X% (where X is some value you need to determine) then no.

Answer (score 7):

If you are smarter than the compiler, you *may* be able to make your code faster on one specific platform by writing it by hand in assembly.

However, most big C/C++ compilers are *extremely* good optimizers; you are unlikely to be smarter than them.

Comment: "However, most big C/C++ compilers are extremely good optimizers" - developers of GCC and ICC cried there.

Comment: I would go so far as to say that if you ask this specific question (ie: writing _any_ routine in assembly rather than C/C++), then you are _not_ smarter than the compiler yet. People who are smarter than the compiler already know which routines they should bother writing in assembly.

Comment: @Nicol: True, but he's asking why his colleague might have chosen to use the inline assembler.

Comment: Inline assembly or separate assembly language modules allow people to take advantage of platform specific hardware, including processor features, that the compiler doesn't know about.  In general, this kind of optimization is only performed when all other optimizations do not yield significant improvement.

Comment: It's even image filtering. This is a classical SIMD application, and extensions like SSE or NEON are really a lot faster than classical C++ SISD code. You might be able to process 8 pixels per instruction.

Answer (score 4):

No, that's not really necessary, and this also **makes porting the app much more different**. This is the main concern about inline assembly.

And, of course, 80% of the time compiler can do this better.

Comment: Tried to tell this more politely :)

Comment: And even if the compiler-generated code is 10% less efficient than the hand-tuned assembly code, which would you rather maintain?

Comment: Is it a question or a statement?

Comment: +1, and ObscureRobot is agreeing with you.  Even if hand-tuned assembly code was faster than the compiler-generated assembly, it's *far* easier to maintain the original C or C++ than it is to maintain the ASM.

Answer (score 4):

1. First find an efficient algorithm.
2. Then implement it in clearly readable code.
3. Then evaluate its performance.
4. If your code's performance is inadequate, consider alternative algorithms
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 until either performance is acceptable or you have exhausted all algorithmic alternatives
6. Drink some coffee.
7. Take a walk.
8. Repeat steps 3 and 4 again some more.
9. Have a beer.
10. Give steps 3 and 4 another few tries.
11. Get some rest
12. Back to 3 and 4.
13. Spend years studying the architecture of the CPU(s) your code will run on
14. Now consider hand-writing some assembly.

Answer (score 3):

> One of my senior collegues optimizes a function (he is implementing image filtering) by writing in-line assembly. Is that really necessary?

Obviously I can't comment on your colleagues exact situation, but I wouldn't be surprised if it was necessary. There's many specialised instructions that are used for image filters that  won't necessarily be used by the compiler. Inline assembly is often the only way to access those instructions (or through intrinsics).

> Wouldn't modern compiler do that for us?

Obviously this depends on what *'that'* is, but while modern compilers are certainly good at generating code, **they aren't magic**. It is often the case where you know something about your code that the compiler doesn't (or can't).

If your line of work involves high performance code then there are definitely places where you can get major improvements from using inline assembly (or even just compiler intrinsics).

> If assembly code really brings lots of benefits, when should we convert C/C++ code into assembly and when should we leave the code as it is, since assembly code is hard to read and maintain.

Here's how:

1. First, profile your code to see what potential benefits are to be gained.
2. Look at the disassembly to see what the compiler is doing. If it is already doing things optimally then there is no point going further.
3. If there are opportunities for improvement, consider using compiler intrinsics before hand-written assembly as it is generally easier to maintain and more portable.
4. Only if all that fails should you go to inline assembly.

Answer (score 3):

I'd imagine that for image filtering you might benefit from e.g. the availability of [SIMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions) instructions, but not all compilers can automatically compile your code to use them, and not all the time. So in-line assembly or [intrinsics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_function) can help with that.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no it's not necessary, the longer answer is... well, it depends. Modern compilers do indeed do a very good job of optimizing code, but they don't necessarily have access to all the assumptions a human does when optimizing.  Hand coded assembler can beat compiled code, but there is a tradeoff between portability and maintenance.

Assuming that you have already determined this bit of code is a hotspot, the first thing you should do is tweak algorithms, then tweak the C++ code to make it faster (for example unrolling loops), and then tweak compiler flags.  As a last resort, if you still can't make it go as fast as you need, consider whether its worth paying the cost of hand-optimizing, given all the future cost you will incur in maintenance and portability.

Answer (score 0):

Where image processing is concerned I would be cautious either way as it depends on the input data, the algorithm and the compiler. Intel's ICC has a very good parallelizer and vectorizer for generating SSE code, it may be hard to beat by hand in *most general purpose* image processing cases. VCC on the other hand might not do such a good job.
However, I would expect that most benefit could be gained using compiler intrinsics rather than inline assembler.

Answer (score 0):

programming languages are very well coded. Unless you are using very simple bitwise operations, like add, bitshift or using pointers or new instruction sets, you should use a practical programming lanugage. you DO NOT need assembly language for anything in your life. standard c operations call the relevant cpu instructions. If somebody makes a new CPU and it supports new instructions and you want to use those instructions, the programming languages or libraries do not support them and adaptation takes time. A new instruction in a cpu, makes things faster but you won't ever work in teams like DirectX or Opengl or MMX, SSE bla bla bla. Think of a day when graphic libraries like directx or opengl were not developed and intel,for say, creates some isntruction sets currently supported by none of the languages or inexistent in none of the libraries developed. then you would want to call some method from cpu and pass your parameters to that, for better performance. You can still do the same things without the new instruction in cpu. Another example, a new cpu by intel can support md5 hash checking, it doesnt mean you can't use md5, it means a library developed which uses md5 instructions will work faster because the cpu has a separate entity inside which will execute the operation efficiently. but normally you would wait until somebody publishes a library which uses md5 instructions int the cpu. cpus today add instrucion sets for zip, hash check, encryption and so on. you would use assembly language for some specific instruction. not for the good old add, multiply, subtract or divide because your programming language is already using them in the most efficient way possible.